# Pipe $_POST to an external command

Tags: php, post, request, pipe

I have a program that reads a JSON request from `stdin`, which I want to call in PHP.
Here's what I have right now

```
<?php
echo exec(
  'echo \''.json_encode($_POST,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).'\' | '.
  'program'
);
?>
```

This works, but is there a more direct way to put a string in PHP in `stdin`?
Something along the lines of `pipe(json_encode($_POST,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK),'program')` maybe?

What I have may be fine in this particular case, but what if instead of JSON, I'll need to pipe binary data? What if it's too long to fit into a shell argument, or contains single quotes?

**Edit**:

Following [miken32](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255289)'s suggestion, I used [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) like this:

```
$proc = proc_open(
  'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar/lib program args',
  array(0 => array('pipe','r'), 1 => array('pipe','w')),
  $pipes,
  NULL
  //, array('LD_LIBRARY_PATH','/foo/bar/lib')
);
if (is_resource($proc)) {
  fwrite($pipes[0],json_encode($_POST,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
  fclose($pipes[0]);

  echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);

  proc_close($proc);
}
?>
```

But I had to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo/bar/lib` to the command argument. The `$env` argument seems to have no effect. Does anyone know why?

Comment: `or contains single quotes` that's what `escapeshellarg()` is for...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: So, did my answer work for you?

Comment: I feel like you only provided half an answer. I needed to pipe data in and out, and your example only pipes it in. Sorry, I don't think I can accept the answer only for the link. I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Ah, your question made no mention of needing output, so I only added it as a footnote. I just noticed your edit though; if you don't want to accept my answer you can post your own answer and mark it as the accepted answer. It's generally frowned upon to edit the question to mark it "solved" while leaving it open.

Comment: And the array for environment needs to be associative, like `["LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => "/foo/bar/lib"]`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that. I'll accept your answer, if you add a `proc_open()` example and what you wrote in your last comment. I thought `echo exec` in my first code snippet would make it obvious that I want to print the output text. Don't remove the `popen()` example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`popen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to create a pipeline to a process:

```
<?php
$data = json_encode($_POST, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$p = popen("program", "w");
fwrite($p, $data . PHP_EOL);
$exit_code = pclose($p);
```

If you need to get data back from the program, things get more involved and you need to use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) instead.

```
<?php
$data = json_encode($_POST, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$fds = [
    0=>["pipe", "r"], // STDIN
    1=>["pipe", "w"], // STDOUT
    2=>["pipe", "w"], // STDERR
];
$dir = "/path/to/working/directory";
$env = [
    "PATH"            => "/usr/local/foo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin",
    "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => "/usr/local/foo/lib/",
];
$p = proc_open("program", $fds, $pipes, $dir, $env);
fwrite($pipes[0], $data . PHP_EOL);
fclose($pipes[0]);
$return = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$err    = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
$exit_code = proc_close($p);
if ($exit_code == 0) {
    // successful return
    echo $return;
} else {
    // error
    echo "ERR: $err";
}
```